# openssl_verify() error while decoding firebase custom token using php-jwt library

Tags: php, firebase, jwt, firebase-authentication

I have generated firebase custom token using [php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) library for custom authentication on Firebase as suggested [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library).

I was trying to decode the generated token using ***decode*** function of same library.

Here is my code.

I have defined private key in my configuration file using following line.
`define("FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY","-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMY_VERY_VERY_LONG_KEY\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n");`

Here is the code to decode token.

`JWT::decode($token, FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY, array('RS256'));`

This code throws following exception.

`openssl_verify(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a public key`

When I am using **HS256** for both decoding and encoding, everything works fine.
But I have to use **RS256** because, ***Firebase custom token needs to be signed with RS256 only***.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this?

Comment: It's probably linked to the fact you're supplying **private key** to functions that expect a **public key**. How about you extract public key into a separate variable / constant and pass that, instead of private key?

Comment: @Mjh: Do you mean I have to create a public key from the private key which is available. And then send that public key to the decode function?
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: untested, based on what I know (at the moment).

[`openssl_verify`](http://php.net/openssl_verify) accepts **public key** as parameter, as per documentation. 
You are supplying **private key**.

I'd try to extract public key from the private key, and use that in the `JWT::decode` method.

How to extract the public from private? Quite easy:

```
define("FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY","-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMY_VERY_VERY_LONG_KEY\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n");

$private = openssl_pkey_get_private(FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY);
$details = openssl_pkey_get_details($private);

// Here's your public key, it's presented as a string, not a resource
$public = $details['key'];
```

Comment: This is apparently algorithm dependent. I can decode using the private key if using HS256, but with RS512 it only works using the public key.